# Python selenium - no search results showing when search button is clicked

Tags: python, selenium

I have successfully automated Edge (and Chrome) to the correct page for searching broadband prices and also entered a postcode into the search box. However, when I click the search button, it doesn't show me the results of that search. I need to get the results for several postcodes and scrape the results to pandas eventually. I have identified the search button successfully (I believe) via different methods (Xpath, CSS selector) but the clicking and returning of results is not working automatically. The website works fine when used normally (not automating it).

Here is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

#Other imports here
import os
import wget


driver = webdriver.Edge('msedgedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.thinkbroadband.com/packages")

# Cookie consent button click
consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]"))).click()
consent2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button[1]"))).click()

# inputting postcode
postcode_input_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div/div/div/form[1]/div[1]/input")))
postcode_input_box.send_keys("se19qu")

# identify search button
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='broadband-package-search']/form[1]/div[2]/input")))

# Click the search button - neither method works
#search_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
search_button.click()
```

I know there's some process of interrogating a database of results for the postcode but I'm not sure how to automate that without using the web page elements I've used here.

Many thanks.

Update:
There is a table of results present by default before searching but it is non-specific.
When a search is done on a postcode it states it on the page, see image:

[Image of search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X9qV.png)

This is the output I can't generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your code, the cookie elements were not showing up, and hence the cookie consent elements were failing. I used a try/except to overcome this. It works:

```
    driver.get("https://www.thinkbroadband.com/packages")
# Cookie consent button click
try:
    consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]"))).click()
    consent2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button[1]"))).click()
except:
    print("Cookie Consent Elements Not Found")
    pass
# inputting postcode
# Looing through twice to input search (as the first search is not fetching the results but the subsequent one is)
for _ in range(2):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "packages")).perform()
    postcode_input_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='broadband-package-search']//input[@type='text']")))
    postcode_input_box.clear()
    postcode_input_box.send_keys("se19qu")
    # identify search button
    search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Search']")))
    # Click the search button - neither method works
    #search_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    search_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
eles = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='packages']//tr")))
ls = [ele.text for ele in eles]
# print(ls)
df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
    Cookie Consent Elements Not Found
                                                    0
0   Provider\nPackage\nDownload Speed\n(average)\n...
1   ADSL Broadband + Phone\nby VISPA\n24\nMbps\nUn...
2   Broadband\nby Timico\n24\nMbps\n10\nGB £54.00 ...
3   Unlimited Broadband\nby Timico\n24\nMbps\nUnli...
4   Broadband Unlimited\nby Vivaciti\n24\nMbps\nUn...
5   Business Broadband Unlimited\nby Vivaciti\n24\...
6   Broadband 360\nby FastNet\n24\nMbps\nUnlimited...
7   Unlimited Broadband\nby FastNet\n24\nMbps\nUnl...
8   Essential Broadband\nby FastNet\n24\nMbps\n50\...
9   WF Business ADSL\nby Watchfront\n24\nMbps\nUnl...
10  icuk Home Option 3\nby ICUK\n24\nMbps\n10\nGB ...
11  Provider\nPackage\nDownload Speed\n(average)\n...
12  icuk Home Option 5\nby ICUK\n24\nMbps\n50\nGB ...
13  icuk Business Option 3\nby ICUK\n24\nMbps\n20\...
14  icuk Business Option 5\nby ICUK\n24\nMbps\n100...
15  Home::1 Base\nby AAISP\n21\nMbps\n200\nGB Free...
16  Home::1 High usage\nby AAISP\n21\nMbps\n300\nG...
17  Home::1 Base + Phone Line\nby AAISP\n21\nMbps\...
18  ADSL Lite\nby IDNet\n20\nMbps\n50\nGB Free £19...
19  ADSL Unlimited\nby IDNet\n20\nMbps\nUnlimited\...
20  ADSL Lite + Phone\nby IDNet\n20\nMbps\n50\nGB ...
21  ADSL Unlimited + Phone\nby IDNet\n20\nMbps\nUn...
22  Office 20M Unlimited\nby Total Web Solutions L...
23  Provider\nPackage\nDownload Speed\n(average)\n...
24  BT Business Broadband\nby BT\n17\nMbps\n10\nGB...
25  BT Business Unlimited Broadband\nby BT\n17\nMb...
26  BT Business Unlimited Broadband Premium\nby BT...
27  BT Business Unlimited Broadband + Phone + UK C...
28  Home User (100GB)\nby CloudScape\n16\nMbps\n10...
29  Home User Unlimited\nby CloudScape\n16\nMbps\n...
30  Business User (100GB)\nby CloudScape\n16\nMbps...
31  Business User Unlimited\nby CloudScape\n16\nMb...
32  Home Worker\nby Amatis Networks\n16\nMbps\nUnl...
33  Office\nby Amatis Networks\n16\nMbps\nUnlimite...
34  Office (M)\nby Amatis Networks\n16\nMbps\nUnli...
35  Provider\nPackage\nDownload Speed\n(average)\n...
36  Office Plus\nby Amatis Networks\n16\nMbps\nUnl...
37  Office Plus (M)\nby Amatis Networks\n16\nMbps\...
38  ADSL Business 100 GB\nby Stream Networks\n16\n...
39  ADSL Business Unlimited\nby Stream Networks\n1...
40  ADSL Annex M Business 100 GB\nby Stream Networ...
41  ADSL Annex M Business Unlimited\nby Stream Net...
42  Home Phone & Unlimited Broadband **special off...
43  Origin Broadband + Phone\nby Origin Broadband\...
44  Unlimited Broadband + Phone Package\nby Zen In...
45  Unlimited Broadband + Phone **1 month contract...
46  BT Broadband Essential\nby BT\n10\nMbps\nUnlim...
47  Provider\nPackage\nDownload Speed\n(average)\n...
48  Unlimited Business Broadband and Phone\nby Plu...
49  Unlimited Broadband + Home Phone **£60 reward ...
50  Unlimited Broadband + Apple TV 4K **extra 10% ...
51  Unlimited Broadband **save £2.50 if an EE mobi...
52  Unlimited Business Broadband **1 month contrac...
53  Unlimited Business Broadband + Phone Package *...
54  Unlimited Business Broadband Office + Phone Pa...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the scraping example, it will come in handy when I get it working. Unfortunately, the information you see is not filtered by postcode. See my update above.

Comment: @KenShabby I tested your application manually, and what I discovered is this: On the first search attempt with `se19qu`, the search results are: `WOW, Virgin Media, UltraFast`, etc, which were there by default upon the page visit, which infers that the search is not happening on the first search click. When after this search is done, we search again with `se19qu`, a new result is being fetched, the output of which you can see in my modified answer now. Consequently, I have modified the code to make the search twice, and the code is updated, as well as the result. Check if this is what's needed

Comment: Also, I have changed the locators to make it more relative. Yours were absolute xpaths, which are not efficient. I could not find the cookie consent and hence left the locator as is, but if you find it, please make the locator relative.

Comment: Thank you @Anand, this solves the problem brilliantly. I had no idea of these methods. The only downside is that it is quite slow which has an impact on the number of postcodes I can search (my client is hoping for thousands).  A great solution though, thanks.

Comment: @KehShabby, you can do two things: (1) reduce the `time.sleep` and see if it still holds good - you can at least save a couple of seconds for each iteration (2) The best thing to to is to extract with API if your client could provide it. It would be remarkably faster than selenium

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the class or the css selector in my experience the css selector works when the xpath doesn't

CSS selector:
.submit

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion.